# Asp.net 500 error

Tags: asp.net

I am loading daily data into access which is being displayed in an asp.net page.  The access table has no issues, but when it goes over 1063 rows of data, the asp page will not display the data and gives the 500 error.  It does not matter what time frame is inserted it is always 1063 rows. There is nothing in the code to "set" a limit.  Has anyone ever run into this?

Comment: A 500 error means there is a problem server side. You should investigate the actual error message. That will give you a hint what it could be. Without it it it would become guesswork.

Comment: Completely agree with VDWWD's comment. Check the Event Viewer on the server, often the error that is causing the 500 will get logged there.

Comment: Please add the part of code which breaks